# Merge two workbooks based on a key column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have two workbooks which I need to merge.  On workbook_1 I have column A with 5 letter codes and in column B I have numbers for what is on hand.  On workbook_2 I have column A with the 5 letter codes, but some are different and some are the same as in column A from workbook_1.  On column B this time I have numbers for what is authorized.
I need to combine column A from both workbook_1 and workbook_2 and keep the numbers from column B from both workbooks.

For example:

**Workbook_1**

```
Column A:  Column B:    
CODE       ON HAND
ZWRAA      2
TRSAA      5
RSTAA      6
TRWA1      4
TRWA2      8
TRWA3      3
```

**Workbook_2**

```
Column A:  Column B:
CODE       AUTH
ZWRAA      5
TRSA1      6
TRSA2      9
TRWAA      7
TRWA2      2
YTSAA      1
```

This is what I need to see after I combine both workbooks:

```
CODE    ON HAND  AUTH
ZWRAA   2        5
TRSAA   5        0
TRSA1   0        6
TRSA2   0        9
RSTAA   6        0
TRWAA   7        0
TRWA1   4        0
TRWA2   8        2
TRWA3   3        0
YTSAA   0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a join. You'll probably get more Google hits if you search for "spreadsheet join"

This has been [answered on superuser before](https://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql)